# Print a specific stars pattern using select query in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I want to print

```
*
**
***
****
```

and continue like this using select query in oracle.

```
select substr('*****',1,level) from dual connect by level<=5
```

If I write the above code it will print but it will be dependent on the number of Stars I put in my code.

```
select substr('*****',1,level) from dual connect by level<=9
```

Like in this case it will not work and will stop after 5 stars only. can anyone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a `lpad('', level, '*')`

```
select lpad('', level, '*') 
from your_table
```

eg:

```
select lpad('', level, '*')  from dual connect by level<=5
```

in this way the number of start depend of the level value

Comment: yes that will work. can we do it using substring? anyway thanks.

Comment: what do you mean with "can we do it using substring" ? .. explain better

Comment: I want to mean the way I was trying to write the query using the substring function,can it be done in that way?

Comment: Yes .. but your you should use connect by  on real Hierarchical value .. try add a real table schema and data sample .. connect the parent to the chidl  ..and use the pseudo column for buil a dinamic string using lpda or substring ..

Comment: @Be1ng_Kr1Sh - only if you have a longer initial fixed string of asterisks (i.e. 9 or more); or replace that fixed string with an`lpad()` call to generate the string - but then substringing that is kind of pointless. But `substr()` on its own can't add extra characters.